# Receiving a Type Mismatch error when attempting to break up my array formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My array formula was too long so I was attempting to use the replace method of getting this formula into the sheet however, when I run the code I get a type mismatch error on the first replace line. Not sure what is causing the issue here:

```
Dim X0 As String
Dim X1 As String
Dim X2 As String

X0 = "=IF(COUNTIFS(R2C1:R5000C1,RC[-21],R2C20:R5000C20,RC[-2])>1,RC[-16]-INDEX(Cash!R2C41:R5000C41,MATCH(SMALL(IF(Cash!R2C40:R5000C40=RC[-21],ABS(Cash!R2C41:R5000C41-RC[-16])),1),IF(Cash!R2C40:R5000C40=RC[-21],ABS(Cash!R2C41:R5000C41-RC[-16])),0)),""X1"")"
X1 = "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-21],Cash!R2C42:R5000C59,18,0)=1,RC[-16]-VLOOKUP(RC[-21],Cash!R2C40:R5000C41,2,0),IF(AND(VLOOKUP(Deposits!RC[-21],Cash!R2C42:R5000C61,18,0)>1,VLOOKUP(Deposits!RC[-21],Cash!R2C42:R5000C61,18,0)<>""""),RC[-16]-VLOOKUP(RC[-21],Cash!R2C42:R5000C61,8,0),VLOOKUP(Deposits!RC[-21],Cash!R2C42:R5000C61,20,0)))"
X2 = "=IF(RC[-11]>0,IF(OR(RC[-2]=""Mix"",RC[-2]=""Possible Mix - Review Date""),""X0"",IF(Deposits!RC[-2]=""Non-Cash Transaction"",Deposits!RC[-16],"""")),"""")"


With ActiveSheet.Range("V2")

 .FormulaArray = X2
 .Replace """X0""", X0
 .Replace """X1"")", X1
 End With
```

A1

```
Dim X0 As String
Dim X1 As String 
Dim X2 As String
Dim X3 As String

X2 = "=IF(K2>0,IF(OR(T2=""Mix"",T2=""Possible Mix - Review Date""),""X0"",IF(Deposits!T2=""Non-Cash Transaction"",Deposits!F2,"""")),"""")"
X0 = "IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5000,A2,$T$2:$T$5000,T2)>1,F2-INDEX(Cash!$AO$2:$AO$5000,MATCH(SMALL(IF(Cash!$AN$2:$AN$5000=A2,ABS(Cash!$AO$2:$AO$5000-F2)),1),IF(Cash!$AN$2:$AN$5000=A2,ABS(Cash!$AO$2:$AO$5000-F2)),0)),""X1"")"
X1 = "IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Cash!$AP$2:$BG$5000,18,0)=1,F2-VLOOKUP(A2,Cash!$AN$2:$AO$5000,2,0),""X3"")"
X3 = "IF(AND(VLOOKUP(Deposits!A2,Cash!$AP$2:$BI$5000,18,0)>1,VLOOKUP(Deposits!A2,Cash!$AP$2:$BI$5000,18,0)<>""""),F2-VLOOKUP(A2,Cash!$AP$2:$BI$5000,8,0),VLOOKUP(Deposits!A2,Cash!$AP$2:$BI$5000,20,0))"

With ActiveSheet.Range("V2")

 .FormulaArray = X2
 .Replace """X0""", X0, xlPart
 .Replace """X1"")", X1, xlPart
 .Replace """X3"")", X3, xlPart
   End With
```

Comment: If you are putting this in row 2 how can you have `R[-15]`?

Comment: Put the array formula into the cell(s) and make the replacements there.

Comment: you are correct my formulas are a bit off but not sure that this is the cause of my issue?

Comment: I believe the issue is once you put it in the cells it no longer is in R1C1 format and you are trying to input the string with r1c1 directly in the formula without forcing VBA to see it as a formula in R1C1 format.  You are going to want to put the whole formula at least the parts you are replacing in A1 format.

Comment: Also you are going to want to get rid of the `=` in front of the two strings X0 and X1.  You do not put `=SUM(=IF(...,0,=IF()))`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the xlA1 formula in the top left cell of your target range.

Comment: I updated it with the right formula in R1C1 now I am only getting the error on the final replace for the X1

Comment: will try to do in A1

Comment: but if you look at the formula in the v2 it does not include the first replacement.  It comes down that you are mixing R1C1 and A1 at that point and Excel can't figure it out.

Comment: Tried it in A1 and am still getting the type mismatch error at the second replace location

Comment: Turns out X1 was still too long created another replacement string and now it is taking it. Thanks for the assistance fellas

Comment: Have a new problem now. It is only doing the replacement of X0 and X2. X1 and X3 are not even being appended to the formula.. I will paste new code under A1 at the top

Comment: removed the ) in the replacements and now its working

Comment: VTC because OP solved the issues and hasn't been active on site